when disabling intel RST, unable to activate C drive
I am following intel rst guide to disable it for my dell laptop.
After changing the registry values and enabling ahci from bios, windows couldn't restart(as given in guide). 
Then in the command prompt when running diskpart (v 10.0.22621.1) after making the changes in drive names, we are unable to activate the volume in which windows is installed.
When we do active it says
The selected disk is not a fixed MBR Disk.
The ACTIVE command can only be used on fixed MBR Disks.

My output on list volume is
Volume 0 || F || DATA       || NTFS || Partition || 731 GB || Healthy || 
Volume 1 || C || OS         || NTFS || Partition || 222 GB || Healthy || 
[...]
Volume 3 || E || WINRETOOLS || NTFS || Partition || 990 MB || Healthy ||  

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS version, alongside windows 11.
Edit 1: list disk showed me that both my disks are GPT, so can we even do active on non-MBR disks.
Edit 2: Issue got solved!
list disk
select disk X (replace X with your disk with windows) 
list volume 
select volume Y (replace Y with your EFI System Partition (esp) number) 
assign letter=Z (assign an available letter to the EFI partition) 
exit

cd /d Z:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot 
bcdboot C:\Windows /s Z: /f ALL

 I choose the esp partition of my windows disk, and then when i generated the boot files on z, it started working.

Intel RST is (most likely) a software raid technology and as such it creates a header on your disk. Somehow when you switch between modes Windows is getting confused.

I choose the esp partition of my windows disk, and then when i generated the boot files on z, it started working.
list disk
select disk X (replace X with your disk with windows) 
list volume 
select volume Y (replace Y with your EFI System Partition (esp) number) 
assign letter=Z (assign an available letter to the EFI partition) 
exit

cd /d Z:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot 
bcdboot C:\Windows /s Z: /f ALL

